# Word meaning "changing career paths often in a short period"

Tags: word-request

I'm currently writing a personal statement, and since English is not my native language I sometimes have trouble with transferring my ideas onto paper in English. Here's what's currently troubling me:

> I've always wanted to be a scientist. Throughout my younger years I __ ...

What I want in the blank is a word which conveys that before I chose physics, I actually went from scientific field to scientific field and read about a variety of scientific topics. Basically that I hopped from field to field before I settled for physics. What word can I use here?

Comment: Great question! You did a very good job of explaining what you were looking for. I hope you stick around and ask more questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them are a single word, but there are many ways to express this. The following is not at all a comprehensive list, but a few options you could choose from:

> Throughout my younger years I **vacillated between** several different scientific fields before I settled on physics.
>
> Throughout my younger years I **was indecisive regarding** the field I wanted to go into. I eventually chose physics.
>
> Throughout my younger years I **moved from field to field** often before I ultimately decided physics was my calling.

Any of these would be acceptable, and I'm sure there are many more. I came up with a few others but they all had a slightly negative connotation (ie. "in hindsight I wish I hadn't done this"). If you're curious, I've listed them below:

> Throughout my younger years **my career path was a bit erratic**, but I eventually decided on physics.
>
> Throughout my younger years **I was a bit mercurial** when it came to what field I worked in. I eventually realized that physics was right for me.

Comment: Those are some great suggestions, I will most certainly use one of them!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind being a bit informal, I'd suggest ***bounced around***:

> Throughout my younger years I *bounced around* from specialty to specialty, but I eventually settled on physics.

The phrase can be used when describing the process of considering a range of options. Here's an excerpt from a [blogger](http://vjssalon.com/another-happy-customer/for-years-i-bounced-around-from-salon-to-salon/) who used that phrase:

> *For years I bounced around from Salon to Salon, while one did great cuts it did not do color well. And another would do great color but average cuts*.

Comment: That's a good one, and it also fits my level of vocab. I'll certainly consider it.

Comment: As a native speaker, this is *exactly* what I would say, if I was being honest. If I was trying to downplay the fact that I bounced around a bunch, I might instead say "I tried a lot of different things."

Comment: @Andrew: Quite. Your second one (downplay any earlier "lack of career focus") seems to be the only one out of all the suggested answers/comments that comes close to being a sensible choice if OP actually *wants* the job (as opposed to wanting to bare his soul). There are probably even better ways to phrase it - surely a more broad-based background could be presented in a *positive*, rather than negative or neutral light!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite hard to write without the risk of a negative implication. It shouldn't be, of course; the best way to spend your youth is trying a lot of things in order to find out what you like!

Perhaps something like:

> In my youth I was interested in a broad range of scientific topics before deciding to concentrate on physics.